# Iframing an iframe protected page

Tags: iframe

This's for education purpose only:

if we have an iframe protected page or site (when you iframe the site it will break the iframe and redirect o home page) how can we overcome this protection and force iframing of this page

i tried many time with no luck

Comment: Out of curiosity, if it's your page, why would you want to or need to do that?

Comment: @vch just for learning